# Error while running "npm start": 'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

**I am having this error while running "npm start" command on terminal as I am trying to build a cryptocurrency tracker using React.js**

**my package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-crypto-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "11.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.0"
  },
  "description": "This is a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project bootstrapped with [`create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app).",
  "main": "next.config.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Error:-

'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nextjs-crypto-api@0.1.0 start: `next start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nextjs-crypto-api@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-20T16_58_19_379Z-debug.log

**Please help me with this error**

Comment: Try `npm install` first, and then `npm start`. Also, you may want to post a redacted version of your package.json

Answer (score 3):

### Please read your WARNING first

**npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?**

That means you are trying to run the project without installing the node_modules beforehand.

So, you should be doing - first

```
npm i
```

and then

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue with modules. I am not sure but try deleting your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder and then try below commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then again run

```
npm i or npm install
```

Comment: Please can you update the answer in case I don't want to reinstall npm because I'm working with very large project.

Comment: @User He's not telling you to reinstall npm but your libraries (modules). Npm is telling you that this project has NO libraries installed (node_modules folder missing) so you are not even reinstalling, you are installing for the first time

Comment: npm i - won't hurt to your project anyway. sometimes, it needs a refresh to the modules. Once you delete modules and run npm i - it will create modules again with all your project dependencies and your project will stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here until I realized I had an outdated version of Node.js installed.

Make sure to install the latest version of Node.js, then delete both the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file in your project.

Reinstall the node_modules:

```
npm install
```

Then run it using:

```
npm run dev
```

The above command is different from `npm start` because you're using Next.js

Answer (score 0):

You should check your dependencies thoroughly, as they are compatible depending on the version of "devDependencies" that is being used. If you are using an outdated version and wish to update to a recent version, it could be the possible cause of your error. Review your package.json file and verify the dependencies. It could be helpful to review your git log and then run

```
npm install
```

or

```
"npm i"
```

to ensure all dependencies are properly updated.

You can use the "git diff" command in the terminal to view the changes made to a specific file. For example, if you want to see the changes made to the file "example.txt", you can run the command

```
git diff package.json
```

Recently, I encountered this problem but I was able to resolve it by carefully reviewing my dependencies and checking which versions were being used. By comparing the versions in my package.json

Here I am showing you the solution that I could give to my project which presented a similar case.

[image]

I would recommend checking each of the dependencies necessary for your project.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios as part of next.js

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.2"
  },
```

**Development Case:-**

1. **npm run dev**, it will start the development server
2. ***localhost:3000***

**Production Case:-**

1. **npm run build**, it will build production ready code
2. **npm run start**, your appplication will be loaded from the Build, when we achieved step 1
3. ***localhost:3000*** , will serve the application.